# Blazor Wasm Hosted. .Net 6.0. Problem AAD Authentication

Tags: azure-active-directory, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

When I try to Authenticate with AAD in Blazor WebAssembly Hosted and .Net 6.0, and, after authenticating, I have the following error trying to access to /WheaterForecast controller:

WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The audience 'api://11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111' is invalid"

**In AAD, I have the following:** 
*Server Application* 
Client Id:   11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111
Tenant Id:   22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222
URI Id App:  api://11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111

*Client Application* 
Client Id:   33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333

Then, my **Server** application config is:

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "xxxxxx.emea.microsoftonline.com",
    "TenantId": "22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222",
    "ClientId": "api://11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  }
```

In the program.cs ...

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
...
...
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

My **Client** application config...

```
"AzureAd": {
"Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/fff3a238-b26a-4351-8a2a-0b19dc72e02e",
"ClientId": "33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333",
"ValidateAuthority": true
```

}

Program.cs from client app...

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ReservasSalasAuth.ServerAPI", client =>
 client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
.AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("{MyNamespace}.ServerAPI"));
 
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("api://11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111/API.Read");
});
```

And the last thing has no good smell is almost always I log in, the popup stays until I press F12 in the Edge...and the continues and finalize the popup.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Audience value is  either client id or app id uri which is set on ‘expose an api’ blade in app registration depending on the app.

Please check the possible work arounds:

1. Check your jwt token in http://jwt.io .If the issuer i.e; "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXX/v2.0",has v2 enpoint.Check the manifest of your azure ad app: Below value is probably null or one, should be two:"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2, Check the same for present  app registrations ,modify if required and try login.

[image]

(or)

2. First Try login  by removing api:// in client id  in server api settings  .If not also remove api:// prefix for options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add in client configure services.

(or)

3. In client app,for Implicit grant, select the checkboxes for Access tokens and ID tokens.
   Make sure you add [api permissions](http://Note:%20(Make%20sure%20you%20have%20given%20permissions%20in%20portal%20too%20same%20as%20code%20config%20and%20added%20it%20to%20scope%20and%20granted%20permissions)) in portal too same as code config and added it to scope and granted permissions).
   Make sure you are logged in with work or school account.

Please check the content under **access token scopes** in [Secure an ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly hosted app with Azure Active Directory | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-3.1#access-token-scopes-2) and inspect if *double api://* scheme is present and try add ap:// or remove if required from scopes .

Comment: Than you very much. Finally it's a mix to make it working. In my case, I needed to make your first and second option. The second, only in the server App.