# Portainer CE with OAuth2 using Azure AD

Tags: authentication, oauth, azure-active-directory, portainer

I would like to ask how to properly setup the authentication for **Portainer CE v2.9.3 using OAuth2 with Azure AD**.

The following fields in the `Custom OAuth2` UI needs to be filled:

- `Client ID`
- `Client secret`
- `Authorization URL`
- `Access token URL`
- `Resource URL`
- `Redirect URL`
- `Logout URL`
- `User identifier`
- `Scopes`

Currently, I use the following values:

- `Client ID`: `<tentant id>`
- `Client secret`: `<created secret for the app in Azure AD>`
- `Authorization URL`: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/`](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%60)`/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
- `Access token URL`: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/`](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%60)`/oauth2/v2.0/token
- `Resource URL`: https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo
- `Redirect URL`: `<our internal URL for the Portainer deployment>`
- `Logout URL`: `<our internal URL for the Portainer deployment>`
- `User identifier`: email
- `Scopes`: `<Application ID URI>`

When using these values, I get the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
        "message": "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": <some date>,
            "request-id": <some request id>,
            "client-request-id": <some client request id>
        }
    }
}
```

I need to use **Portainer CE with the Customer OAuth Provider**.

Thank you for any usefull advice.

Answer (score 0):

**Possible causes of Audience invalid error and workarounds**

1. Client ID must be either the ApplicationId   or ApplicationIdUri
   depending on the app configuration.(not tenant Id)

> Note :first try `clientId:<Application Id>` and if that is giving the
> same error , change clientId to ApplicationIdUri i.e;    `clientId:api://<Application Id>`

[image]

2. Scope is something that you see under add a scope blade .

[image]

3. When you click on add a scope ,you can mention any permission and it appears as a scope like below:

[image]

4. This scope must be in `scopes` value
5. Make sure to grant admin consent if required if app registration has permissions.

Example:

[image]

---

2. Another is the end point from which you are getting the token maybe different . Try to decode access token in https://jwt.io and see “ISS” value  has v2 endpoint .If it has V2 endpoint,
   in azure Active directory, Go to Manifest and change “accessTokenAcceptedVersion”:2 .Also check that Audience value i.e; “AUD”  must match the client Id  .The audience invalid occurs if they doesn’t match.

[image]

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70034199/blazor-wasm-hosted-net-6-0-problem-aad-authentication/70043891#70043891)